# pfsense opnvpn cannot access local VPC Subnet IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, pfsense, amazon-vpc

I have setup PfSesne in OpenVPN on AWS in a VPC subnet. private subnet range is 10.0.0.0/24 . it has one EIP . i want to connect to internal LAN subnets by vpn access. i do have enabled the option to enable local neywork access from openvpn client, but i am only able to ping the pfsense private IP only, and not any other IP in the network. Though, the packets do reach to pfsense from opnvpn client but after that what it does to packets? i am not able to figure out.

I have enabled all access from security groups , the servers, which i need to access from vpn client , i can access them using the pfsense without any issues, but not from vpn client. Also, pfsense firewall has all traffic allowed. 
VPN local network is set to 172.16.1.0/24, i have tried changing vpn networks too, that if they might be causing conflict with other networks on pfsense, but not worked

Here is configuration:
[image]

Comment: Do the VPC route tables have a route for 172.16.1.0/24 that points to this instance's instance ID?  Did you disable source/dest check for this instance?

Comment: already disabled source/dest check . but not sure about route. let me check

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: i have added routing entry as well, but still not working